# Overloading Console.ReadLine possible? (or any static class method)

Tags: c#, class, static, console, overloading

I'm trying to create an overload of the `System.Console.ReadLine()` method that will take a string argument. My intention basically is to be able to write

```
string s = Console.ReadLine("Please enter a number: ");
```

in stead of

```
Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't think it is possible to overload `Console.ReadLine` itself, so I tried implementing an inherited class, like this:

```
public static class MyConsole : System.Console
{
    public static string ReadLine(string s)
    {
        Write(s);
        return ReadLine();
    }
}
```

That doesn't work though, cause it is not possible to inherit from `System.Console` (because it is a static class which automatically makes is a sealed class).

Does it make sense what I'm trying to do here? Or is it never a good idea to want to overload something from a static class?

Comment: Can you not just create your own static class that just works on the Console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the console in your own class and use that instead. You don't need to inherit for that:

```
class MyConsole
{
    public static string ReadLine()
    {
        return System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string ReadLine(string message)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(message);
        return ReadLine();
    }
    // add whatever other methods you need
}
```

Then you can go ahead and use that one in your program instead:

```
string whatEver = MyConsole.ReadLine("Type something useful:");
```

If you wish to push it a bit further and make `MyConsole` a bit more flexible, you could also add support to replace the input/output implementations:

```
class MyConsole
{
    private static TextReader reader = System.Console.In;
    private static TextWriter writer = System.Console.Out;

    public static void SetReader(TextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        }
        MyConsole.reader = reader;
    }

    public static void SetWriter(TextWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        }
        MyConsole.writer = writer;
    }


    public static string ReadLine()
    {
        return reader.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string ReadLine(string message)
    {

        writer.WriteLine(message);
        return ReadLine();
    }
    // and so on
}
```

This would allow you to drive the program from any `TextReader` implementation, so commands could come from a file instead of the console, which could provide some nice automation scenarios...

**Update**
Most of the methods that you need to expose are extremely simple. OK, a bit tedious to write perhaps, but it's not many minutes of work, and you need to do it only once.

Example (assuming we are in my second sample above, with assignable reader and writer):

```
public static void WriteLine()
{
    writer.WriteLine();
}

public static void WriteLine(string text)
{
    writer.WriteLine(text);
}

public static void WriteLine(string format, params object args)
{
    writer.WriteLine(format, args);
}
```

Comment: If I do it that way, I'd have to remember to use `MyConsole` for `ReadlLine()`, but use `Console` for any other Console method. If inheritance would be possible, I could just use `MyConsole.WriteLine()`, `MyConsole.Clear()` or any other `Console` method.

Comment: @comecme: the idea would be to have `MyConsole` to wrap all methods that you would need to use (which typically are not that many).

Comment: You can wrap every method of Console in your own class and achieve the same net effect.

Comment: @Fredrik: If I want to wrap the `Write` and `WriteLine` methods into MyConsole I'd have to wrap each overload of Write and WriteLine I'd like to use, right? So maybe it's not that many methods, but there are a lot of overloads.

Comment: @comecme: you are correct, there are a few overload. But in the end, you can typically wire the calls so that there is only one or two of them doing actual work, the rest can be one-liners calling another overload with default arguments.

Comment: @comecme: it's in fact even easier; most of the methods that you want to use, maps directly to calling the corresponding method on the underlying `TextWriter` or `TextReader`, so you can just propagate the call without any further processing in most cases (will add examples).

Comment: For some reason I accidentally down-voted this and I am unable to revoke the down-vote? Any idea how I can undo this??

Comment: @BenPretorius not sure, but I think that you can click the downvote arrow again to "toggle" it. If not, no worries :-)